# readUTFBytes from remote file

Tags: apache-flex, file, flex4

Is it possible to `readUTFBytes` from a remote file without prompting the user with the download screen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use `URLLoader`.

```
private var loader:URLLoader;
private var req:URLRequest;

private function init():void {
    loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    req = new URLRequest("..."); //url
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(req);
}

private function onComplete(event:Event):void {
    ByteArray(loader.data).readUTFBytes(100);
}
```

Comment: Who's awesome? Yes you are. Thanks!

Comment: @Francisc You should also look into URLStream, whose sole purpose is downloading data. URLLoader works just fine, but URLStream will give you much more fine control over the download that URLLoader doesn't offer (as URLLoader is meant to be used for loading data into an app, rather than saving it to the system as it seems you wish to do).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. Indeed, I was trying to readUTFBytes in order to writeUTFBytes.